# Logical Thinking: Using Dynamic vs Static Values to Represent Data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, variables, logic

I don't think I am asking the question correctly, but hopefully you know what I am asking.

What are pros and cons of using a string value to represent a database field (or any variable) vs using an enumeration or constant? I am not asking about the datatype, but hows its handled on the back-end. I'll use LINQ to SQL for an example.

My thinking is that by using an enumerable or constant it's: easier to read, ensures compatibly should the values ever need to be changed, and the value is hard coded -so to speak- so there are less chances of an error caused by a typo. On the flip side, do I really need a class/structure with member enumerations that essentially act as a look up for the value I want?

**Using an Constant**

```
Module Trip
  Public Const OPEN As String = "Open"
  Public Const PENDING_PAYMENT As String = "Pending Payment"
  Public Const CANCELLED As String = "Cancelled"
  Public Const CLOSED As String = "Closed"
End Module

Dim product = From p In db.Payments
       Where p.PaymentId = PaymentId

For Each item In product
  item.Status = PayStatus.PENDING_PAYMENT
Next
```

**Using a string**

```
Dim product = From p In db.Payments
       Where p.PaymentId = PaymentId

For Each item In product
  item.Status = "Pending Payment"
Next
```

Comment: I don't Think this will work at all, First dose your `item.Status` return `String` OR `Byte`? if it's String Then you can't compare it to byte and vice versa.

Comment: Ya you are right, can't convert nvarchar to float. However, what if instead of an Enum I used constants? I will update my code

Comment: Why not use a lookup table in the database for the values of status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the comments says, the common way to deal with this is using a lookup table in the database. In its most simple form, you would have a class, let's say `PaymentStatus`:

```
Class PaymentStatus
    Public Property Id As Integer 
    Public Property Name As String 
End Class
```

and `Payment` would have reference property like

```
Public Property PaymentStatus As PaymentStatus
```

This way, you can always get the options from the database and you will never make a typo in code. It's also much easier to add options or to change descriptions.

For instance, think of what you need to do if you'd decide that "Cancelled" needs to be differentiated into "Cancelled by user" (the old status) and "Cancelled by system" (a new status introduced by new business logic). You'd need a script to update all records in the database to the new string (and change the code, but you'd be changing code anyway). A lookup table allows you to update only one record (and add a new one in this example).

Comment: You absolutely can make a typo because you have to somehow find the enum row representing a cancelled status. I'd want to see a list of advantages of using an enum table before I'd implement such a thing. It seems to be most useful if the enum members are runtime-changable.

Comment: @usr That's right. In reality I would (and did) combine this with an enum type. But I would never use string literals when they get stored repeatedly in the database, that's the main point. I'm awaiting the OP's response to see if we're on the same page and maybe some follow-up is desired.

Comment: @GertArnold With performance in mind- would you say this is the best way, or just a common way? Do the advantages you listed of a look up table outweigh the performance hit? Would the expense of joining a table with just a few rows even be noticeable?

Comment: It depends on the query provider. If you use Entity Framework or Linq-to-sql you can also have a primitive property like `PaymentStatusId` in `Payment` and simply query `Where PaymentStatusId = <some value>`, so you don't always have to join with the lookup table. For display purposes you do have to join which, yes, theoretically may hit performance, but probably won't (not noticeably so) because `PaymentStatus` is a very small table.